# Скачать все открытые вкладки в браузере

Tags: html, веб-программирование, браузер, расширения, imacros

как скачать все открытые в браузере вкладки? Может, есть какая-то комбинация клавиш, может плагин? Именно скачать, а не добавить в закладки! То есть совершить действие CTRL+S!
У каждого файла в итоге обязательно должно быть уникальное имя. Причем не важно, пусть это будет даже:
файл.html
файл(1).html
Суть в том, что нужно сохранить все вкладки и всё)

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью imacros. Для удобства также стоит установить расширение Tab Count Icon или аналогичное.
Работает в FireFox версий 35 - 56.02 + iMacros плагин версии 8.9.7

```
TAB T={{!LOOP}}
SAVEAS TYPE=CPL FOLDER=* FILE={{!LOOP}}+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}
WAIT SECONDS=3
```

Переходите на первую вкладку, вводите количество повторов и нажимаете Воспр. (Цикл). Для понимания, также можете прочитать подробную справку об использовании команды [SaveAs на русском языке](http://www.imacros.org/komandy/saveas)

Для работы imacros с версиями FF старше 56.02 и Chrome придётся покупать лицензию, чтобы разблокировать возможность работы с файлами .